# Math script size changed between unicode-math v0.8e and v0.8g?

Tags: luatex, subscripts, unicode-math, superscripts

I have just compiled an existing document using a more recent version of `unicode-math` and noticed that a lot of line/page breaks were different. The reason seems to be that the sizes of sub-/superscripts in math mode changed somewhere between `unicode-math` versions 0.8e and 0.8g.

For example, using the minimal document

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    x^Ax^Bx^Cx^Dx^Ex^Fx^Gx^Hx^Ix^Jx^Kx^Lx^Mx^Nx^Ox^Px^Qx^Rx^Sx^Tx^Ux^Vx^Wx^Xx^Yx^Z
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

`unicode-math` 0.8e yields

[image: unicode-math 0.8e output]

while `unicode-math` 0.8g gives

[image: unicode-math 0.8g output]

My questions is whether this is intentional/expected? In the [release notes for `unicode-math` 0.8g](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/releases/tag/v0.8g), I see

> - Better use of scriptstyle sizes in LuaTeX (I think a regression).

and indeed, as far as I can tell, only LuaTeX seems to be affected?

Comment: The chosen size for the superscripts used to be 8pt like in standard LaTeX, now it's 8.41483pt, for both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg Hm, interesting. Do you know if there is some kind of advantage to this new choice that’s worth it to make a breaking change?

Comment: I'm not sure the effect was actually wanted.

Comment: Opened issue at https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/478

Comment: @barbarabeeton The document uses 12pt

Comment: @egreg -- oops!  missed that.  will delete comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited to provide more details**

I managed to track down the related changes made in v0.8g. In particular, the follow code was introduced in `um-code-main.dtx`:

```
\cs_new:Nn \@@_declare_math_sizes:
  {
    \dim_compare:nF { \fontdimen 10 \g_@@_trial_font == 0pt }
      {
        \DeclareMathSizes { \f@size } { \f@size }
          { \@@_fontdimen_to_scale:nN {10} \g_@@_trial_font }
          { \@@_fontdimen_to_scale:nN {11} \g_@@_trial_font }
      }
  }
```

We see that the `unicode-math` package *intentionally* overwrites the declaration of math sizes at `\normalsize`. This is because OpenType math fonts contain additional parameters `ScriptPercentScaleDown` (`\fontdimen10`) and `ScriptScriptPercentScaleDown` (`\fontdimen11`). For OpenType Latin Modern Math, these are `70` and `50`, respectively.

Therefore, in a `12pt` article, the intended font sizes (according to the new `unicode-math`) for first- and second-level scripts are `8.4pt` and `6pt`, respectively. Note that the LaTeX kernel legacy declarations are `8pt` and `6pt` for first- and second-level scripts in `12pt` text. So, you would observe slightly larger first-level scripts using `unicode-math`.

---

There are more subtle differences in `12pt` article between pdfLaTeX’s `\usepackage{lmodern}` and XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX’s `\usepackage{unicode-math}` with OTF LM Math.

In the pdfLaTeX case, the design sizes used at text-size, script-size and script-script-size are `LMMathItalic12`, `LMMathItalic8` and `LMMathItalic6`, respectively.

But in the XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX case with `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, the text-size uses `OTF LM Math 10pt` font scaled up to `12pt`, the script-size uses `OTF LM Math 7pt` font scaled up to `8.4pt`, and the script-script-size uses `OTF LM Math 5pt` font scaled up to `6pt`.

---

**Addendum**

The strange `8.41483pt` for the first-level script is due to the improper order of floating-point arithmetic.

I have [provided a fix for the rounding error](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/478#issuecomment-446607874) (not for honoring the original math size declarations, as I believe we should use the OpenType parameters) in the issue opened by @egreg:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Nn \__um_fontdimen_to_percent:nN
  {
    \fp_eval:n { \dim_to_decimal:n { 65536 \fontdimen #1 #2 } / 100 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    x^Ax^Bx^Cx^Dx^Ex^Fx^Gx^Hx^Ix^Jx^Kx^Lx^Mx^Nx^Ox^Px^Qx^Rx^Sx^Tx^Ux^Vx^Wx^Xx^Yx^Z
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

<del>Hopefully this will be implemented soon.</del> This has made into the source code of `unicode-math`. So no more rounding errors, yeah!

Comment: Remember that the actual question was mainly about version differences between 0.8e and 0.8g. So what you’re telling me is that this change is expected/intentional (rounding errors notwithstanding)? In my opinion, changes to line/page breaks are very disruptive and should be clearly marked.

Comment: @Socob You are correct! This change in math size declarations you've observed in version 0.8g of `unicode-math` is indeed intentional. Will Robertson and I are discussing this in https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/478, and hopefully egreg can also provide some insights. Long story short, `unicode-math` decided to use OTF parameters instead of LaTeX kernel legacy declarations, which unfortunately would result in `8.4pt` script-size instead of `8pt`.

Comment: @Socob I should also mention the more subtle differences in `12pt` article between pdfLaTeX's `\usepackage{lmodern}` and XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX's `\usepackage{unicode-math}` OTF LM Math. In the pdfLaTeX case, the design sizes used at text-size, script-size and script-script-size are LMMathItalic12, LMMathItalic8 and LMMathItalic6, respectively. But in the XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX case with `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, the text-size uses LM Math 10pt font scaled up, the script-size uses LM Math 7pt font scaled up and the script-script-size uses LM Math 5pt font scaled up.

Comment: @Socob I edited my answer to better reflect your original question. :)